# Como guardar credenciales en powershell para enviar email Office 365

Tags: email, powershell, office365

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo electronico desde Powershell el cual he logrado correctamente pero tengo un problema al adjuntar el usuario y la contraseña en el script el codigo es el siguiente:

```
# Email account variables
$emailUserName = "user";
$emailPassword =  "password";
$smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com";

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString  $emailPassword -AsPlainText -Force



$to = "mail@mail.com;mail@mail.com";


$emailParams = @{
    To = $to.Split(';')
    From = "${emailUserName}"
    Subject = "Alerta backup kistler"
    Body = "No se ha creado el backup"
    SmtpServer = "${smtpserver}"
    Port = 587
    Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($emailUserName, $securePassword)
    UseSsl = $true
}

Send-MailMessage @emailParams
```

Y recibo el siguiente error:

> Error: 535 5.7.139 Authentication  unsuccessful, the user credentials
> were incorrect. [SA1PR05CA0018.namprd05.prod.outlook.com]

Sin embargo puedo iniciar sesion correctamente directamente en Office 365 Online, se que el error es porque no esta encriptada correctamente la contraseña, porque si el usuario y la contraseña los ingreso de la siguiente manera:

```
Credential = Get-Credential
```

Por lo que requiero que el usuario y la contraseña quede directamente en el script para poder automatizarlo, ¿alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Sigues teniendo el problema? La pregunta es muy antigua. Es imprescindible hacerlo desde PShell?

Comment: Para Office 365, es posible que debas habilitar la autenticación de dos factores y generar una contraseña de aplicación para usar en tu script. La contraseña de la aplicación es una contraseña generada por el sistema que puedes usar con aplicaciones que no son compatibles con la verificación en dos pasos. Una vez generada, puedes usar esta contraseña de la aplicación en lugar de tu contraseña normal en tu script